# Using multiple packages in Perl for writing API server module using JSON::RPC::Server

Tags: json, perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures, json-rpc

I have written a server module for using JSON::RPC::Server and am trying to import more than one package (using `use`). This is the code for the `Server.pl` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use JSON::RPC::Server::Daemon;
use add2Num;

JSON::RPC::Server::Daemon->new(LocalPort => 42337)
                          ->dispatch({'/jsonrpc/API' => 'add2Num'})
                          ->handle();
```

And this works fine. However, I want to import (`use`) another file for, let's say, subtraction. I have tried rewriting the server module in 2 ways like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use JSON::RPC::Server::Daemon;
use add2Num;
use sub2Num;

JSON::RPC::Server::Daemon->new(LocalPort => 42337)
                          ->dispatch({'/jsonrpc/API' => 'add2Num'})
                          ->dispatch({'/jsonrpc/API' => 'sub2Num'})
                          ->handle();
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use JSON::RPC::Server::Daemon;
use add2Num;
use sub2Num;

JSON::RPC::Server::Daemon->new(LocalPort => 42337)
                          ->dispatch({'/jsonrpc/API' => 'add2Num', 'sub2Num'})
                          ->handle();
```

Both of these give me a "Procedure Error" when I attempt to access the subtract function which is written in `sub2Num`. I followed [this link](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-RPC-0.96/lib/JSON/RPC/Server.pm) for the syntax of `dispatch`. Could someone please tell me my error?

Comment: I know nothing of this, but it looks like you're saying "dispatch requests for /jsonrpc/API to add2Num and requests for /jsonrpc/API to sub2Num", which makes no sense.

Comment: @ikegami - does this mean I may need separate urls for separate modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the [code for the module](https://metacpan.org/source/DMAKI/JSON-RPC-1.03/lib/JSON/RPC/Legacy/Server.pm#L67) (well, almost), I think your assumption is right. You cannot have two modules for the same path.

```
elsif (ref $arg[0] eq 'HASH') { # Lazy loading
    for my $path (keys %{$arg[0]}) {
        my $pkg = $arg[0]->{$path};
        $self->{dispatch_path}->{$path} = $pkg;
    }
}
```

It will accept multiple key/value pairs of paths and modules in dispatch, so there is no need to call dispatch twice. But it will only allow one module per path. Your second call to `dispatch` with `sub2Num` was overwriting the previously set `add2Num`.

Without trying anything of this, I see a few solutions:

- use the array ref syntax `dispatch(['add2Num', 'sub2Num')` and figure out where to set the path that the daemon is bound to (most likely)
- build an additional module which imports both `add2Num` and `sub2Num` to combine them and `dispatch({'/jsonrpc/API' => 'combinedNum})`
- add the support you need to the module and submit it as a patch to the author (least likely)

Comment: Thanks for this. I was thinking along the lines of the second option that you gave. I'm writing and testing that now. I'll let you know how that goes in a few hours. Thank You.

Comment: I looked at the code some more. If you use the array ref version, it will just use all modules' methods for all paths I believe. That should work. Also, the code contains an awful lot of string evals and I can't see why right now.